# Type inference in TypeScript dictionaries

Tags: typescript

Imagine a fictive example of modelling a vehicle store:

```js
type Vehicle<TClass extends string, TSpecs> = {
    class: TClass,
    specs: TSpecs
}

type Truck =     Vehicle<'truck',      { horsePower: number, maxLoad: number }>
type MotorBike = Vehicle<'motor-bike', { maxSpeed: number }>
type Boat =      Vehicle<'boat',       { name: string, type: 'fishing' | 'cargo' }>

type SalesCatalog<TClasses extends string> = {
    [vehicleClass in TClasses]: Vehicle<vehicleClass, any>[]
}
```

I could create an example store by:

```js
let localStore: SalesCatalog<'truck' | 'boat'> = {
    boat: [
        { class: "boat", specs: { name: 'Gunnar', type: 'fishing' } },
        { class: "boat", specs: { name: 'Titanic', type: 'cargo' } }
    ],
    truck: [
        { class: 'truck', specs: { horsePower: 300, maxLoad: 5000 } }
    ]
}
```

I get two benefits from TypeScript:

- The union type `'truck' | 'boat'` ensures, that `localStore` must contain both keys
- The key of the dictionary is aligned with the contained value. So ex. Only objects with `class: "boat"` is allowed under the key `boat`.

However, the `specs` property is still of type `any`, and I can't find a way to tell TypeScript, that a `boat` class infers a payload of `{ name: string, type: 'fishing' | 'cargo' }` in a `SalesCatalog`. Ideally I would like to declare a SalesCatalog by

```js
let localStore: SalesCatalog<Truck|Boat> = ...
```

But that doesn't work. So my question is: is it possible..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell which spec belongs to which class without using the concrete classes, so the best you can do is to use them:

```
type SalesCatalog<T extends Truck|MotorBike|Boat> = {
  [vehicleClass in T['class']]:  (T&{class:vehicleClass})[]
}
```

with this you can use `SalesCatalog<Truck|Boat>` and have a proper type check for spec

Comment: Your solution makes the `specs` property align with the `class` property, which is good. But it also allows for ex. trucks to be stored under the 'boat' key, which is not the intention.

Comment: @Mal that's true, so we'll have to bring `Vehicle` back to the scene. I updated the answer, have a look

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the alignment of dict key and `class`, but it broke the consistency between `class` and `specs` property (the type of `specs` is now always `(Truck|MotorBike|Boat)["specs"]` instead of `any`, so it's an improvement, but it allows a boat's spec to reside in a truck object.

Comment: Your current answer might be the optimal answer, so I will accept it, if nothing else shows up

Comment: @Mal third time's a charm, have another look :)

Comment: Why is this `type SalesCatalog<T extends Truck|MotorBike|Boat> = {
  [vehicleClass in T['class']]:  Vehicle<vehicleClass, T['specs']>[]
}` not good? @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: @AviadP. it breaks class-specs dependency, so you can create a boar with specs of a truck

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova It keeps getting better (: This aligns the dict key with the `class` value AND ensures, that `specs` contains all properties of the corresponding class of vehicle. However, `specs` is also allowed properties, that reside outside of it's corresponding class (ex. trucks are now permitted to have a type: 'fishing' property)

Comment: @Mal updated again (have fun breaking it :D)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova This is beautiful! And simpler. And it works perfectly. Thank you so much for this. I'm excited to realize, that an optimal solution exists, and to bring these findings into my own context now :)